# What does this black-font Israeli stamp on my Passport mean?

Tags: israel, passport-stamps, visa-rejections

I applied for B2 Tourist visa at Israel embassy in New Delhi last week. But my visa application got rejected and stamped a black stamp on my passport.

What does black stamp mean? After how much time should I reapply for tourist visa?

[image]

Comment: It says: `A visa request has been submitted on 2/11/2017 in New Delhi`

Comment: How many times I can reapply for Israel tourist visa?

Comment: Did they give you any information about the reason for the rejection?

Comment: No, they don't give information about the reason for rejection.

Comment: Do you have any follow-up information to this question? What happened after this? Did you go? You can write that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I have reapplied for B2 Tourist Visa in the first week of December 2017 and successfully got visa on second attempt.

Comment: I would add your comment as an edit.  It can be useful for other readers, in the sense that they could try and reapply, too.

Answer (score 12):

As @NeanDerThal correctly commented, this is **not a rejection**.

The stamp says, in Hebrew, "A visa request has been submitted. Place: New Delhi. Date: 2/11/17" (i.e. November 2nd 2017).

If this is why you think your application was rejected, you can relax - it was not rejected. I couldn't find reliable information about processing times, but it should take at least a week (one site says 14 business days).

I hope you enjoy your Christmas in Israel.

Comment: But I got my passport back with no Visa printed on the page?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works. Perhaps you'll need to bring it back for stamping after a decision is made. But I'm sure that this stamp is not a rejection.

Comment: Maybe Israel embassy also follows same as what Hungarian Embassy in Doha told me; They put a stamp on Page when application received; If Visa Approved that sticker covers that stamp; if visa not approved no rejection stamp; but all future embassies will see & can use the information that this person applied for Israel Visa & because no sticker, they will automatically deduce that that visa might be rejected. Did OP get a rejection letter too even a basic one saying Your Visa Application is not successful?

Comment: No, I haven't got any rejection letter.