# Do the Israeli consulates give visa on a separate piece of paper instead of on the passport?

Tags: visas, passport-stamps

I applied for a visa in the Israeli consulate here in NYC. I have just received the confirmation of visa from the Israeli consulate in NYC. I have heard that Israel do not give the visa on the passport. Instead, they paste it on a separate piece of paper and make like a travel permit and they also do not stamp the passport/or any ID during immigration. Is that true?

Comment: I can confirm that they give entry permits at the border on a separate piece of paper, but I have no experience with ahead-of-time visas.

Comment: If you're posting here under your real name, I would advise you to change it immediately, since what you're doing is not allowed under Bangladeshi law. Instructions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site/85820

Answer (score 3):

Are you allowed to travel to and fly in and out of Israel *proper*? If yes, is your visa a regular tourist visa or a special case?

I'm asking because although Israel does not ban citizens of countries that do not recognise its existence and have no diplomatic ties with it, it only permits visit/tourist visas to a minimum group of 10 people to visit the Palestinian territories including the Aqsa mosque in Jerusalem. They need to enter and exit from Jordan-West bank border crossing and be accompanied by a security official at all times. Source is timatic (except the security detail which comes from secondhand reports)

In any case, since Bangladesh passport states it's not valid for travel to Israel, you will not get visa stamped in your passport nor will you get entry/exit stamps. Instead you will get a permit on a separate sheet which would be stamped on entry and exit.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! 
It is a regular B2 tourist visa.
I totally get what you are saying, that they give a "permit" on a separate sheet. I have met people with such cases.

Comment: @Supantho Raxit, do you plan to fly into Ben Gurion airport? Have you checked with the Israeli embassy if you can do that? I'd love to hear what the embassy says and please could you return to update us about the trip when you're back? Thanks!

Comment: yeah I am flying to Ben Gurion Airport. I will check with the embassy and update!

Comment: I believe you are describing rules for visa-on-arrival. Are there also such restrictions for visas issued in advance, and if so, link please?

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus, VoA only after clearance from responsible Israeli ministry for entry through Jordan border. There's no other options available AFAIK. I will be surprised if individual Bangladeshi nationals are allowed to travel to Israel proper and land at TLV. That's why I asked the OP to update us as it would be an invaluable firsthand report of its kind for citizens of countries that don't recognise Israel.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to believe that Israel has no problem issuing an individual visa in advance to Bangladeshis. The Bangladeshi may suffer legal problems at home, though. Bangladesh isn't even on the list of anti-Israeli countries needing special confirmation (e.g., Iran and Saudi Arabia). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Israel

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus, timatic says that Bangladeshis require confirmation from Israeli MFA. But wiki reference does not mention that. One of the countries on the list (Pakistan) that require MFA confirmation has the exact same requirements on timatic as the Bangladesh passport holders. The info is conflicting.

Comment: @Marbles I tried Peru. I think the information about details of entry via the Occupied Territories is all-country boilerplate. It's not a requirement that Bangladeshis (or Peruvians) enter via Jordan.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, that's interesting. So we can take it to mean that Bengladeshis can visit Israel individually as long as they have a valid visa and so can citizens of countries that don't recognise the state of Israel.

Comment: I think so. That is, the list of countries that don't recognize Israel is much larger than the list of countries whose nationals need special visa confirmation from the Ministry in Israel.

Answer (score 3):

I entered the country the 10/06/19 via the Ben Gurion airport, and was given the **piece of paper** shown at the top below. No stamp on passport. As you can see, is a standard B2 tourist visa, lasting for 3 months. Importantly, I did not ask for a separate paper. I was paying a lot of attention to the people before me and in other queues, and I never saw or heard a passport being stamped.

On the way out through the same airport, before you do the check-in/bag drop, you must show the paper with the visa to the security people (so keep it!). Then, while passing through the departure gates, you are given the another piece of paper shown bottom below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's clear now. It would still be useful to know what country's passport was shown, as it's a data point about what passports (if any) are stamped directly, and what others (perhaps all) generate the visa/entry document as a separate paper.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Israeli visas are stamped on the passport, which can be a problem for you. However, your circumstances are quite unique - Israel normally doesn't grant visas to citizens of countries that don't recognize it - so it's possible that things would be different.

Why I think they stamp the passport:

- A Google image search for "Israeli Visa" shows some visas that seem to be stamped on the passport.
- In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104777/52465) a Hebrew stamp saying "A visa request has been submitted" is stamped on the OP's passport.

If your passport is indeed stamped (you'll find out soon enough), then it may get you in trouble when returning to Bangladesh. I really don't know how strict are the Bangladeshi authorities about it. In some countries (e.g. Iran) it could make you a suspected spy. You might want to report the passport lost.

P.S. you might want to read [this story](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Bangladeshi-banned-from-home-country-for-visiting-Israel-returns-to-Jewish-State-515238) - a Bangladeshi doctor who's the first Bangladeshi national to ever visit Israel, and is now banned from Bangladesh (he's also a "loud and proud pro-Israel activist who is converting to Judaism", which surely doesn't improve his situation in Bangladesh).